How to retrieve a List of Pipelines in azure data factory for a Specific Branch?
I need to retrieve a list of pipelines in Azure Data Factory (ADF) and are associated with a specific branch in a specific repository within Azure DevOps.
Azure DevOps Pipelines
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Azure DevOps REST API: I used the following API call in powershell to retrieve details from the branch in the repository, as the pipeline details are stored inside ADF/pipelines, but this is not giving me the expected result:
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/items?path={path}&scopePath={scopePath}&recursionLevel={recursionLevel}&includeContentMetadata={includeContentMetadata}&latestProcessedChange={latestProcessedChange}&download={download}&$format={$format}&versionDescriptor.versionOptions={versionDescriptor.versionOptions}&versionDescriptor.version={versionDescriptor.version}&versionDescriptor.versionType={versionDescriptor.versionType}&includeContent={includeContent}&resolveLfs={resolveLfs}&api-version=5.0

I got this response from the above request, but my expectation was to retrieve the list of adf pipelines triggered from a specific branch.
count : 1
value : {@{objectId=xxxxxx; gitObjectType=tree; 
        commitId=xxxxxx; path=/ADF/pipeline; isFolder=True; url=https://xxxx.xxxx.xxx
        /xxxx/xxxxxxxx/_apis/git/repositories/xxxxxx/it
        ems?path=%2FADF%2Fpipeline&versionType=Branch&version=Main&versionOptions=None}}

PowerShell Module: I used Get-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline to list pipelines in the Data Factory:
Get-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -DataFactoryName <DataFactoryName>

But, this cmdlet returns pipelines in the live mode in the Data Factory environment, not the Devops pipelines.

my expectation was to retrieve the list of devops pipelines published in adf, how do you publish DevOps pipeline in ADF? And what's ADF/pipelines folder content? Please elaborate a bit and show what you want to get.

ADF/pipelines contain the list of DevOps pipelines,

DevOps pipeline yaml is .yaml or .yml format, please show a screenshot of ADF/pipelines folder content to confirm. How do you publish devops pipeline in ADF?

I have added the picture in the body. It's a json file not yml like DevOps pipelines.

As you may already notice, the json file in ADF/Pipeline folder is NOT DevOps pipeline, but they are ADF pipelines. In the Json file, it will have "name" in the json to display the pipeline name. I will add the details below, thanks.

@denim did the below answer helped you?

As per the json files screenshot, they are ADF pipelines actually. In DevOps git repo, it will have the name in the json file as below:

If you want to get the ADF pipeline name from DevOps git for specific branc, eg: Develop, you can checkout the branch, and get the name value from the json.
Yaml sample below:
pool:
  vmImage: Windows-latest

steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true                 # keep credential for git command latter.

- powershell: |
        git fetch --all
        git checkout Develop                  # for Develop branch
        # Get all JSON files in the "ADF/pipeline" folder
        if (Test-Path -Path "ADF/pipeline") {
          $jsonFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "ADF/pipeline" -Filter *.json -Recurse
          foreach ($file in $jsonFiles) {
              $jsonContent = Get-Content -Path "ADF/pipeline/$file" -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
              $pipelineName = $jsonContent.name
              Write-Output "Branch: Develop, PipelineName: $pipelineName"       # output branch name and pipeline name.
          }
         } else {
            Write-Output "Path 'ADF/pipeline' not found, skipping..."
        }

It can get the pipeline name:

